# Can I do a ListDensityPlot with a equation?

Tags: plotting

If I only have this equation: 0.311235 - 0.0034967 x + 0.0725721 x^2 + 0.0124099 y - 0.0000277583 x y + 0.0726165 y^2

How can I do a density plot?

Comment: Read(!) and try `DensityPlot[ "your equation" ,{x,...},{y,...}]`

Answer (score 1):

Three different ways to view the function:

`f = 0.311235 - 0.0034967 x + 0.0725721 x^2 + 0.0124099 y - 0.0000277583 x y + 0.0726165 y^2;`

`ContourPlot[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`

[image]

`Plot3D[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`

[image]

`DensityPlot[f, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`

[image]

More specifically, the following code works:

`fn[x_, y_] :=  0.311235 - 0.0034967 x + 0.0725721 x^2 + 0.0124099 y -  0.0000277583 x y + 0.0726165 y^2;`

`data = Partition[Flatten[Table[{x, y, fn[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5, 1}, {y, -5, 5, 1}]], 3];`

`ListDensityPlot[data]`

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in the definition of `data`. Also, `Partition` is unnecessary if you `Flatten` to the appropriate level. `data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, fn[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5, 1}, {y, -5, 5, 1}], 
   1];` This correction will make the plot resemble the others.

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon fixed, ty